# Границы border CSS

Tags: html, css, border

У меня текст выровнен по центру и у него обводка. Можно ли что бы эта обводка была в границах текста и дальше не лез

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#headed{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #70B8FF;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  border:5px blue dashed;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\ВЛАД\AtomProject\FirstWeb\style.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="headed"><span><b>About Me</span></b></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. Бордер у вас вроде для блока, а не для текста. Куда он не должен лезть? Чуть больше подробностей по проблеме бы.

Comment: Нужн что бы рамка была под текст меньше а не на всю страницу

Comment: может есть макет? Или сам нарисуешь как нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#headed{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #70B8FF;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  border:5px blue dashed;
  display: block;
  padding: .2rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 160px;
}

.flex-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    -ms-flex-item-align: center;
    align-self: center;
    }
    
.flex-item h1 {
  padding: .2rem;
  border: 6px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\ВЛАД\AtomProject\FirstWeb\style.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="headed">
       <strong>About Me</strong>
     </div>
     <!-- flex -->
     <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item">
          <h1>About Me</h1>
        </div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: по центру выровнять нельзя?

Comment: @AquaGF добавьте `margin: auto;`

Comment: Спасибо помогло